# Formatting date value in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

HTML

```
<input type="datetime-local" onblur="window.setValue(this.value)" />
```

[image]

JS

```
window.setValue = function (val) {
    console.log(val);
}
```

The output above is `1991-03-02T00:01`, how to get the exact value? Like `03/02/1991 12:01 AM`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: Personally, I'm a huge fan of http://momentjs.com and http://momentjs.com/timezone/

Answer (score 0):

```
function formatDate(date) {
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  var format = hours < 12 ? 'am' : 'pm';
  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12; // making 0 a 12
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
  var time = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + format;
  return date.getMonth()+1 + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear() + " " + time;
}

var date = new Date();
var output = formatDate(date);
alert(output);
```

Demo
http://jsfiddle.net/64oyzhng/3/

Comment: To show one digit minutes with 0
for example 9 as '09'

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty easy to do using just javascript, as demonstrated by @chrana. There are also a number of libraries which use javascript's native `Date` object and allow formatting, [`moments.js`](http://momentjs.com/) is one of them. I have also been working on a library which will also allow formatting dates by using standard [`CLDR notation`](http://cldr.unicode.org/translation/date-time) but does not rely on `Date`, instead everything is done in pure math, for accurate astronomy dating.

The format that you have shown is very similar to the standard US short date, except you have no `,`

```
03/02/1991, 12:01 AM
```

But using my library and any library using CLDR notation it could be done like this.

```
MM/dd/Y h:mm a
```

```js
require.config({
    paths: {
        'astrodate': '//rawgit.com/Xotic750/astrodate/master/lib/astrodate'
    }
});

require(['astrodate'], function (AstroDate) {
    "use strict";
    
    var date = new AstroDate('1991-03-02T00:01');

    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(date.format('MM/dd/Y h:mm a')));
});
```

```html
<script src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.8/minified/require.js"></script>
```