# function is not defined in onblur?

Tags: javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/58gw8sr7/

My html

```
<input type="datetime-local" onblur="formatDate(this.value)" />
```

my function

```
    function formatDate(date) {
..
..
}
```

Comment: Your fiddle loads it in the window load event. Also, paragraphs don't have a value attribute, use innerHTML instead.

Comment: `formatDate` is defined in the `load` event handler, so it's not global. But inline event handlers can only call global functions. So get rid of inline event handlers and use `addEventListener`

Comment: This is an exact duplicate... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27751096/formatting-date-value-in-javascript and then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27751236/datetime-local-return-nothing-with-onblur-function I'm not sure if it's the same person, but this is the 3rd of this exact question today, all within the last 2 hours or so

Comment: @AaronSwartz Try reformulating your question properly, look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, don't repeat your question multiple times in the forums, it will get marked as a duplicate. Do your research first.

Answer (score 1):

I still stand by the comments that I made below your question, however, I believe this is what you're looking for...

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v7vo0wqx/)

The code takes into account the browser's support for the `datetime-local` input type and sets the output accordingly.

The output will be the one stated in your other posting of the question from this link:[Formatting date value in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27751096/formatting-date-value-in-javascript) having the format:"03/02/1991 12:01 AM" and if the browser supports the `datetime-local` input type, it will set the date and time accordingly. As far as I'm aware, you cannot change the format of `datetime-local` to the format specified above. If you want to get the format specified above, on browsers that do support this input type, you can always create a hidden input element and set its value to the desired output for processing (as I assume this is the intention).

```js
var support = false;
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.setAttribute('type', "datetime-local");
if (input.type !== 'text') {
  support = true;
}

$("#datetime").onblur = setDateTime();

function setDateTime() {
  var nDate = new Date();
  var string;
  var date = nDate.getDate();
  var month = nDate.getMonth() + 1;
  var year = nDate.getFullYear();
  var hour = nDate.getHours();
  var minute = nDate.getMinutes();
  var second = nDate.getSeconds();
  var millisecond = nDate.getMilliseconds();
  var ampm = "AM";

  if (date < 10) {
    date = "0" + date.toString();
  }
  if (month < 10) {
    month = "0" + month.toString();
  }
  if (support === false) {
    if (hour === 0) {
      hour = 12;
    }
    if (hour > 12) {
      hour -= 12;
      ampm = "PM";
    }
  }
  if (hour < 10) {
    hour = "0" + hour.toString();
  }
  if (minute < 10) {
    minute = "0" + minute.toString();
  }
  if (support === true) {
    string = year + "-" + month + "-" + date + "T" + hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second;
  } else {
    string = date + "/" + month + "/" + year + " " + hour + ":" + minute + " " + ampm;
  }
  $("#datetime").val(string);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="datetime-local" id="datetime" />
```